# Java array gets organized unintentionally

Tags: java, arrays, organization

I am working on an academic assignment and I have everything working but I am wondering why my output puts the numbers in order from smallest to largest.

Can anyone tell me where in my code this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Quenten's Copy");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number[] = new int [1000000]; // initialize first array
    int count[] = new int [1000000]; // initialize second array
    int temp = 0; // intialize integer to hold for comparison
    int i; // intialize loop integer

    System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: "); // ask user for input

    // first loop - takes in user input
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        number[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

     // second loop - checks for reoccurance of numbers
    for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        temp = number [i];
        count [temp]++;
    }

    // final loop - gives the output of the count
    for (i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count [i] > 0) {

            // output statement - tells user each number and how many
            // times each number occurs
            System.out.printf("Number %d occurs %d times\n", i, count [i]);



        }
    }
```

Here is a copy of the output:

```
Enter seven numbers: 12 23 44 22 23 22 55
Number 12 occurs 1 times
Number 22 occurs 2 times
Number 23 occurs 2 times
Number 44 occurs 1 times
Number 55 occurs 1 times
```

As you can see it listed 22 before 23 and etc.  I want it to print in the order it is entered.

Comment: You are making your program such that the numbers are printed from lower to higher. You have `count` array where you are storing the numbers frequency and here the original order is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You assign your int from input to your array:

```
number[i] = input.nextInt();
```

Then later you count them via loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    temp = number [i];
    count [temp]++;
}
```

As you can see, if the number `temp` is `12`, you increase the value of `count` at index `12` by one.

So basically, `count[i] = number of occurrence of number i`

Therefore, when you print the `count` array, you see them in natural order.

If you want to print your items in encounter order, I suggest you to use the `Map` to store the occurrence:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> count = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // LinkedHashMap remember the insert order

for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    temp = number [i];
    if (count.contains(temp)) {
        count.put(temp, count.get(temp) + 1);
    } else {
        count.put(temp, 1);
    }
}
```

And you can print them in order:

```
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
     // entry.getKey is the number
     // entry.getValue is the occurence
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all 2 loops will be approximately infinity loop (1000000 times). Costly operation.

```
 // second loop - checks for reoccurance of numbers
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("app. infinity loop");
}

// final loop - gives the output of the count (also app. infinity)
  for (i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("app infinity loop");
 }
```

I think this will be the best answer ( as like @Manh Quyet)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Quenten's Copy");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number[] = new int[7]; // initialize first array
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: "); // ask user for input

    // first loop - takes in user input
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        number[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    // second loop - checks for reoccurance of numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        int key = number[i];
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    // final loop - gives the output of the count
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.printf("Number %d occurs %d times\n", key, value);
    }
}
```